# GoogleMapReact change marker location every 2 seconds error - setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have the following map.jsx file in my react app, which displays a map on screen. I am trying to add a marker to this map (in a separate component called 'MyGreatPlace') which changes location every 2 seconds. It should just update the marker rather than refreshing the whole map, however i am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: setState is not a function
```

Below is my code:

```
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import './map.css';
import MyGreatPlace from './my_great_place.jsx';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, setState } from 'react';

const Map = ({ location, zoomLevel, markerLat, markerLong }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            changeMarkerLatitude();
        }, 2000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

    const changeMarkerLatitude = () => {
        setState({
            markerLat: markerLat + 50,
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className='map'>
            <div className='google-map'>
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'KeyID' }}
                    defaultCenter={location}
                    defaultZoom={zoomLevel}>
                    <MyGreatPlace lat={markerLat} lng={markerLong} text={'A'} />
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Map;
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this error, or is there an alternative way of updating the marker location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you use the state objects. useState is for functional components, and you invoke it by providing two values. First, the reference to the actual value, and second - the reference to the setter. So `const [stateVal, setStateVal] = useState()` gives you an undefined reference to a state object, and a reference to a  function for updating it. You NEVER mutate the state directly (e.g. stateVal = newVal). You ALWAYS use the setter to mutate the state (which triggers a rerender). You can always initialize the value by passing a value into the `useState()` call. Like this: `setStateVal(newVal)`

```js
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import './map.css';
import MyGreatPlace from './my_great_place.jsx';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, setState } from 'react';

const Map = ({ location, zoomLevel, markerLat, markerLong }) => {
    const [markerLatVal, setMarkerLatVal] = useState(markerLat) // You can put value in here to initialize

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            changeMarkerLatitude();
        }, 2000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

    const changeMarkerLatitude = () => {
    // 'prev' gives you access to the previous state value
        setMarkerLatVal(prev => prev + 50);
    };

    return (
        <div className='map'>
            <div className='google-map'>
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'KeyID' }}
                    defaultCenter={location}
                    defaultZoom={zoomLevel}>
                    <MyGreatPlace lat={markerLat} lng={markerLong} text={'A'} />
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Map;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that makes more sense now

Comment: If you have more issues you can post more code here and we can get you sorted. :)

Comment: I have another question here if you could possibly help. Thanks so much - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199075/apply-changing-markers-array-to-google-map-in-react @JoelHager